# AsyncTask within custom Adapter for gallery

Tags: android

i want to use an asynctask in my custom adpater ImageAdapter to display all images from the phone because of the message too much work on UI Thread. I tried with this code (retrieving the case of a gifview for now) : 
Adapter:

```
 public ImageAdapter(ArrayList<Media> liste, Context context) {
        this.listeImages = liste;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listeImages.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listeImages.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolderPic viewHolder= new ViewHolderPic();

        if (convertView == null) {
             convertView = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.imagegallery, null);
             viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.picGallery);
          //  viewHolder.gifView = (GifImageView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.gifG);
              convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder =(ViewHolderPic) convertView.getTag();
            }

            viewHolder.filePic = new 
File(listeImages.get(position).getPath());
        PopulateGallery populate=new PopulateGallery();

            populate.execute(viewHolder);

            return convertView;
    }
}
```

AsyncTask :

class PopulateGallery extends AsyncTask {

```
        ViewHolderPic viewHolder;
        Bitmap bitmap;


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(ViewHolderPic... params) {
         viewHolder=params[0];
        int widhtPic=(screenWidth/3)-6;
      //  if(!getExtensionFile(viewHolder.filePic).equals("image/gif")) {
           // viewHolder.gifView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444;
            options.inDither = true;
           bitmap = decodeFile(viewHolder.filePic, widhtPic, (int) 
   getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.imageGallery_height));

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

But it's a mess. There are blanks spaces the size of images aren't the same. And sometimes OutOfMemoryError i didn't had before in UI thread. I tried to use :

```
  try {
            populate.execute(viewHolder).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (ExecutionException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But no result.I thought it was because the task wasn't finished before returning convertView but the problem remains. What can i do to fix this thing. Thanks.

Comment: There's the Picasso library it makes downloading and showing images easy

Comment: You can use image libraries available like Glide,picasso,universal image loader..you don;t have to do it via AsyncTask.

Comment: the images with picasso are there but nothing displays. I know that cos onItemClick in my grid view is working and a smaller imageView of the selected image is displaying in my editText. i just use Picasso load(url) and into(viewHolder.imageView)

Comment: It's ok now with a a file on disk storage not from url we load like this : .load(new File(path)) and  not like this : load(path). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso). It is a nice library to handle image related task like showing large image, image from network or others.